# Splice function not working, Actionscript 2

Tags: actionscript-2, splice

I'm trying to remove an element from an array.  For some reason this isn't working.

```
MyArray = ["Fus", "Ro", "Dah", "Blah"];
MyArray.splice[2,1];
trace(MyArray); // returns ["Fus", "Ro", "Dah", "Blah"], splice did nothing to the array.
```

I'm sure I've missed something completely obvious but I've searched multiple forums and they all say that code is correct, but it's somehow not functioning at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `MyArray.splice(2,1);`

Note the brackets! `splice()` is a function so () has to be used.